# My Google Maps implementation goes back after a few seconds to my current location

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I am new at using Flutter and I am implementing Google Maps in my app. The thing is that i implemented a function to get my current location and make the camera move to that position, and I only want to travel to my current location whenever i tap on a FloatingActionButton. The only moment i call these function that gets to my location is when i tap that button, but if im not touching the app, after a few seconds, it redirects to my current location automatically, and i would like to change that so it stops travelling by itself. Here's the implementation related to the Google Maps thing. Thanks!

```
class _MapScreenState extends State<MapScreen> {
  GoogleMapController? _controller;
  Location currentLocation = Location();
  Set<Marker> _markers = {};

  
  void getLocation() async {
    var location = await currentLocation.getLocation();
    currentLocation.onLocationChanged.listen((LocationData loc) {
      _controller
          ?.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(new CameraPosition(
        target: LatLng(loc.latitude ?? 0.0, loc.longitude ?? 0.0),
        zoom: 16.0,
      )));
      print(loc.latitude);
      print(loc.longitude);
      setState(() {
        _markers.add(Marker(
            markerId: MarkerId('Home'),
            position: LatLng(loc.latitude ?? 0.0, loc.longitude ?? 0.0)));
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setState(() {
      getLocation();
    });
  }
```

Comment: This does not look like C++.

Comment: Please note -- be careful when tagging questions.  You put a C++ tag, but there is no C++ code involved in your question.  Persons who have subscribed to the C++ tag will now see a totally unrelated question show up in their list, basically being spam.

Answer (score 0):

I think your app is open on 2 devices. kindly close the app on one device. The map access one device location for some seconds then it accesses another for some time.